# Acumatica - Action "Reverse and Apply Memo" Default Post Period to active financial period

Tags: customization, acumatica

Can a customization be created to set the post period to the current active financial period after pressing the "Reverse and Apply to Memo" action in "Invoices and Memos" screen?

We've noticed the newly created credit memo defaults to the post period of the invoice which could be incorrect if it's credited in the following financial period.

Answer (score 1):

The solution defined below was developed within Acumatica 20.102.0015 and changes the date and post period for the created credit memo on "Reverse and Apply Memo" action to the default of a new document instead of the date from the reversed invoice.

```
namespace AARAMPostPeriod
{
    public class AAARInvoiceEntryExtension : PXGraphExtension<ARInvoiceEntry>
    {
        public delegate IEnumerable ReverseDocumentAndApplyToReversalIfNeededDel(PXAdapter adapter, ReverseInvoiceArgs reverseArgs);

        [PXOverride]
        public virtual IEnumerable ReverseDocumentAndApplyToReversalIfNeeded(PXAdapter adapter, ReverseInvoiceArgs reverseArgs, ReverseDocumentAndApplyToReversalIfNeededDel del)
        {
            if(reverseArgs.ApplyToOriginalDocument) reverseArgs.DateOption = ReverseInvoiceArgs.CopyOption.SetDefault;
            return del(adapter, reverseArgs);
        }
    }
}
```

Default value for reverseArgs.DateOption is typically

```
ReverseInvoiceArgs.CopyOption.SetOriginal
```

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about the receivables side of things, but I did something similar on the payables side.  It isn't exactly what you are asking for, but it is too big for a comment. 
 You may be able to get the general idea from this and apply to your scenario.  The approach I took was to check the period when releasing.

```
protected virtual void _(Events.FieldUpdated<APInvoice.finPeriodID> e)
{
    APInvoice row = (APInvoice)e.Row;
    CheckPeriod(e.Cache, row);
}

#region Release override
public delegate IEnumerable ReleaseDelegate(PXAdapter adapter);
[PXOverride]
public virtual IEnumerable Release(PXAdapter adapter, ReleaseDelegate baseMethod)
{
    CheckPeriod(Base.Caches[typeof(APInvoice)], Base.Document.Current);
    return baseMethod(adapter);
}
#endregion

protected virtual void CheckPeriod(PXCache cache, APInvoice invoice)
{
    if (invoice?.FinPeriodID == null) return;

    string currentPeriod = GetCurrentPeriod(invoice.BranchID);
    if (currentPeriod != invoice.FinPeriodID)
    {
        PXUIFieldAttribute.SetError<APInvoice.finPeriodID>(cache, invoice, "Invalid period");
    }

}

public virtual string GetCurrentPeriod(int? branchID)
{
    PXResultset<Branch> Results = PXSelectJoin<GL.Branch,
        InnerJoin<FinPeriod, On<FinPeriod.organizationID, Equal<Branch.organizationID>>>,
        Where<Branch.branchID, Equal<Required<Branch.branchID>>,
            And<FinPeriod.startDate, LessEqual<Required<FinPeriod.startDate>>,
            And<FinPeriod.endDate, Greater<Required<FinPeriod.endDate>>>>>>  // End Date is the date AFTER the period ends
        .SelectSingleBound(Base, null, branchID, Base.Accessinfo.BusinessDate, Base.Accessinfo.BusinessDate);

    if (Results != null)
    {
        foreach (PXResult<GL.Branch, FinPeriod> result in Results)
        {
            FinPeriod period = result;
            return period.FinPeriodID;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

As you can see, I put an override on the Release to perform my validation which sets an error condition if the period is not current.  The validation is performed by retrieving the current period of the current business date and comparing to the period on the APInvoice.

You could explore leveraging GetCurrentPeriod from the example and put into an override on FieldDefaulting if it helps with your goal.